# is not able to pass data on previous activity in android(Java)

Tags: android, android-activity, barcode

I have two activities

Activity 1 - To add new stock
Activity 2- Containing bar code reader

On Activity 2 I am reading out barcode. code below

```
**    public void handleResult(com.google.zxing.Result result) {
        Log.e("1", "handleResult: " + result.toString(), null);
        Snackbar.make(this.scannerView, "handleResult: " + result.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();

        Intent customIntent = new Intent();

        customIntent.putExtra("product_id", result.toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, customIntent);
        finish();
    }**

On Activity 1

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //       if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String productCode = data.getStringExtra("product_id");
            EditText t1 = findViewById(R.id.name);
            t1.setText(productCode);
        }
//        }
    }
```

But function is not calling on activity 1.

Comment: Format your code properly, it will go a long way towards making your question more readable.

Comment: did you start Activity 2 with `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: It works Dennis K. Thank you